# How to pass reactive form control from child to parent component in angular 2

Tags: angular

I Have nested reactive form, like below

parent HTML

```
<form>
 <child></child>
 <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

child HTML

```
<div [formGroup]="headerSection">
 <input type="text" formControlName="test">
 <!span [hidden]="headerSection.get('test').valid">required</span> 
</div>
```

I want to throw error message in child HTML, but when clicking the parent submit button...

Comment: I guess <!span> is a typo

Comment: hey! did either answer help you, or is there some trouble still? :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see that you are actually passing formgroup to your child? So do that first, then I would add another input, a boolean value that is set to `true` when form has been submitted.

So your parent ts:

```ts
submitted = false;

this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  test: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

Child tag:

```html
<child [headerSection]="myForm" [submitted]="submitted"></child>
```

Then in your child show the form and add the conditions on when to show/hide the validation messages:

```ts
@Input() headerSection: FormGroup;
@Input() submitted: boolean;
```

Html:

```html
<div [formGroup]="headerSection">
  <input type="text" formControlName="test">
  <span *ngIf="!headerSection.controls.test.valid && submitted">required</span> 
</div>
```

Finally a **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txrmfk?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

in angular 2 you must create child's elements as a component with @Input & @Output (as a Emmiter) fields for interaction with parent component.

Comment: Can you provide me example, I am new to angular

Comment: go to official website an angular on address:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction